# training sizes for learning curve

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I wonder about the result of the `learning_curve()` I apply:

```
X_train1_be.shape
> (1360, 2)
y_train1_be.shape
> (1360, 2)

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(grid_best
                                                        , X_train1_be
                                                        , y_train1_be
                                                        , n_jobs=n_jobs
                                                        , scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
                                                        , cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 5)
                                                        , verbose=2
                                                        , shuffle = False
                                                        , train_sizes = [1
                                                                         , round(len(X_train1_be)/10)
                                                                         , round(len(X_train1_be)/5)
                                                                         , round(len(X_train1_be)/3)
                                                                         , round(len(X_train1_be)/2)
                                                                         , round(len(X_train1_be)/1)
                                                                        ]
                                                        )
```

but this results in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-9216e6224b3b> in <module>
     12                                                                          , round(len(X_train1_be)/3)
     13                                                                          , round(len(X_train1_be)/2)
---> 14                                                                          , round(len(X_train1_be)/1)
     15                                                                         ]
     16                                                         )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in learning_curve(estimator, X, y, groups, train_sizes, cv, scoring, exploit_incremental_learning, n_jobs, pre_dispatch, verbose, shuffle, random_state, error_score)
   1257     # use the first 'n_max_training_samples' samples.
   1258     train_sizes_abs = _translate_train_sizes(train_sizes,
-> 1259                                              n_max_training_samples)
   1260     n_unique_ticks = train_sizes_abs.shape[0]
   1261     if verbose > 0:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _translate_train_sizes(train_sizes, n_max_training_samples)
   1341                              % (n_max_training_samples,
   1342                                 n_min_required_samples,
-> 1343                                 n_max_required_samples))
   1344 
   1345     train_sizes_abs = np.unique(train_sizes_abs)

ValueError: train_sizes has been interpreted as absolute numbers of training samples and must be within (0, 230], but is within [1, 1360].
```

In contrast, the following works:

```
grid_best = grid_result.best_estimator_
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(grid_best
                                                        , X_train1_be
                                                        , y_train1_be
                                                        , n_jobs=n_jobs
                                                        , scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
                                                        , cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 5)
                                                        , verbose=2
                                                        , shuffle = False
                                                        , train_sizes = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 10))

> [learning_curve] Training set sizes: [  1  25  51  76 102 127 153 178 204 230]
```

According to this [link](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/learning-curves-machine-learning/), it should work how I try to do in the first place:

> **Deciding upon the training set sizes** 
>   Let’s first decide what training set sizes we want to use for generating the learning curves.
>   The minimum value is 1. The maximum is given by the number of
>   instances in the training set. Our training set has 9568 instances, so
>   the maximum value is 9568. However, we haven’t yet put aside a
>   validation set. We’ll do that using an 80:20 ratio, ending up with a
>   training set of 7654 instances (80%), and a validation set of 1914
>   instances (20%). Given that our training set will have 7654 instances,
>   the maximum value we can use to generate our learning curves is 7654.
>   For our case, here, we use these six sizes:
>
> train_sizes = [1, 100, 500, 2000, 5000, 7654]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue raised already some time ago: [github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7834](http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7834)
Means, at the moment it is not possible and it doesn't seem that things will change soon.

A circumvent for me was to multiply the dataset such that the first hold contains the entire data set.